# Xamarin Binding to iOS block

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Is there a binding sample where iOS passes a block to C# that is later on called from c#?

The only reference to that scenario is here in the blockcallback.
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_types_reference_guide#BlockCallback

Our issue is that the block gets called but it seems to have lost the context, ie: local variables that are supposed to have values get the values lost.

The following is a sample in pseudocode as the code is too complex for a posting here:

Objective-C

```c
void somemethod () { 
  int x = 10;
  Myclass *myobj = [[Myclass alloc] init];
  [myCSharpbinding callsome:123 withBlock:^(int val) {
      myobj.prop1 = val; // fails because myobj is null by the time C# calls the block
      // x is also 0 when c# calls the block
  }];
```

C#

```cs
//ApiDefinition.cs

// method within myCSharpbinding class:
void callsome(int value, [BlockCallback] MyBlock block);


public delegate void MyBlock(int val);
```

Comment: The [BlockCallback] support is pretty new, so there might be bugs. I suggest you file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with a complete test case.

Comment: We have created a bug entry: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15250

Comment: The bug was fixed back in 2013